PHP multidimensional arrays and dynamically changing values
I looked at eval, variable variables and also the post at use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays and am quite foxed!
Consider a large bunch of files that have variables like the following: (the variables don't follow any pattern. There could be multiple levels, multiple different first key in each file, etc.)
<?php

$variableLangFirst['english']['testText1'] = 'This is test Text 1 in a single line';
$variableLangFirst['english']['testText2'] = 'This is test Text 1 in a single line with multiple lines and this is line 1

And this is line 2 and 

        this is line 3
        
        
    and this is line 4';
    $variableLangFirst['english']['testText3'] = 'This is test Text 3 in a single line';


    $variableLangNext['english']['myText1'] = 'This is test mytext1 for a new varioable variableLangNext ';
    $variableLangNext['english']['myText2'] = 'This is test mytext1 for a new varioable variableLangNext in multiple lines

    and this is line 2

    and line 3
     ';


?>

What I want to do is

replace the values in this file automatically
i have a huge bunch of files like the above one.
There could be multiple variables, all of them multidimensional arrays like the above, some with more levels in the array.

This is what I tried:

I read the entire file into an array using file function.
I do a simple explode, to get the list of variables, by each line, and ignore the lines that don't contain the variable, and ignore lines that start with a comment. I don't have comments spanning multiple lines, by the way (/* and */ for example). So far so good
Then i include the above file, so that I can get the variables into the scope
I want to retrieve the arrays in the file containing the text dynamically, get their values, and then, for each dynamically retrieved array, change the value and write out the entire data to a new file
+to sum up, i want a set of arrays like array[0]['variable'] =

The need is: I want to set the variable '$variableLangFirst['english']['testText2']' to a completely new value, all dynamically
With the file function and an explode, there is a $myvar[0]['variable'] with the string value of '$variableLangFirst['english']['testText2']' with and $myvar[0]['value'] with a value of 'This is test Text 1 in a single line'. So while the answer marked as dupe helps, it doesn't solve. I am using it to find a solution. Shall update later if found.
What all i tried:

I tried variable variables, but obviously that doesn't work with multidimensional arrays
I tried eval but that doesn't work with multidimensional arrays neither

I think I am missing something inherently simple and stupid here

I need confirm that you want to perform a replacement within the file instead of during runtime, right?

You should stop using $variableLangFirst['english']['testText2'] notation as it makes zero sense. Should be like variableLangFirst.english.testText2. Then you can easily parse it and access any variable you want.

@shingo Thanks. I want to dynamically access the variables in the file and replace the values at runtime. Eventually write out the new values to another file (typically to translate into another language, where 'english' will be replaced with 'anotherLanguage' for example

Thanks @YourCommonSense. I obviously lack it. can you please give an example where i use the notation you recommend, dynamically please?

just use explode and then loop over results as shown in the dupe question starting from $GLOBALS variable

obviously enough, you need to include this file first

@YourCommonSense I have to point out that the dupe question is about how to get, which could be different from changing, because variables must be assigned by reference in order for them to work.
